# How to efficiently insert ENUM value into table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS snippet_types (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS snippets (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT,
  content TEXT,
  type INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(type) REFERENCES snippet_types(id)
);
```

This schema assumes a one-to-many relationship between tables and allows efficiently maintaining a set of ENUMs in the `snippet_types` table. Efficiency comes from the fact that we don't need to store the whole string describing snippet type in the `snippets` table, but this decision also leads us to some inconvenience: upon inserting we need to retrieve snippet id from `snippet_types` and this leads to one more `select` and check before inserting:

```
SELECT id FROM snippet_types WHERE name = "foo";
-- ...check that > 0 rows returned...
INSERT INTO snippets (title, content, type) values ("bar", "buz", id);
```

We could also combine this insert and select into one select like that:

```
INSERT INTO snippets (title, content, type)
SELECT ("bar", "buz", id) FROM snippet_types WHERE name = "foo"
```

However, if "foo" type is missing in `snippet_types` then 0 rows would have been inserted and no error returned and I don't see a possibility to get a number of rows sqlite actually inserted.
How can I insert ENUM-containing tuple in one query?

Comment: Is the snippet_types fairly static?    If so you can have whatever application that does the inserts have a ENUM defined that has the values, and it passes the ID rather than the string.  If "foo" type is missing then you will have an issue anyway if it is static, if it is not static  you could change your SQL so that if it doesn't exist it inserts it into snippet_types and gets the inserted ID

Comment: @Dijkgraaf the snippet_types isn't fairly static, and also I wouldn't like to hardcode ENUMs into source code.

Comment: Then you need to go with your first approach, check to see if the snippet_type exists, if it doesn't insert it.  Then insert the snippets with the ID either from the select or the snippet_types insert.    As long as you make sure you have an index on name for snippet_types, I wouldn't expect that you would have performance issues.  If you do have performance issues, then you could ask how to make it more efficient.

Comment: An INSERT statement inserts rows to only 1 table. The standard way to do what you want is to execute 2 separate INSERT statements. Of course before the 2nd INSERT statement you have to retrieve the id of the inserted type. This can be done in some programming languages by the function used to insert the type, or if the language does not support this by a SELECT statement like the one in your code or by using SQLite's function `last_insert_rowid()`: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid

Comment: @forpas I assume that the full set of ENUMs is already inserted in `snippet_types` upon inserting into `snippets` so enum in question is either present in `snippets` or insertion in `snippets` must fail.

Comment: So what you are asking is how to get feedback when the insertion of the snippet fails because of a missing snippet_type?